# Syntax error using sed for a find and replace

Tags: sed

I am trying to do a find and replace using sed. I am trying to find that : `purge: [],` to replace by `purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],` but it does not work, here is my commande :

```
sed -i -e 's/purge: [],/purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],/g' myfile.txt
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Not possible unfortunately: The point is that this seems to be a commandline, but that commandline is first subjected to shell interpretation and only then passed as argument vector to `sed`. That means, without knowing the shell, it's impossible to tell how `sed` is actually called. For a first step, add an `echo` statement in front of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Change delimiters to a char other than a `/`, like `~` or `!`, or escape `/` delimiter chars inside the pattern (I'd suggest the former)
- Escape the `[` char in the pattern.

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's!purge: \[],!purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],!g' myfile.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/v2eSJW):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Blah..purge: [], blah...'
sed 's!purge: \[],!purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],!g'<<< "$s"
# => Blah..purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"], blah...
```